# Does cordova webview run html5 faster than native webview?

Tags: android, html, cordova, webview

I'm new in android. I did make some search there a topic told about this but not much. I have html5 game and made for android use native webview with hardware accelerate. It run quite good on bluestacks but slow on lg optimus G 4.1. Run little better on lg G2 4.2 but laggy. I heard cordova webview is a wrapper with some better features. I tried all day to wrap and test but face a lot of errors. Would somebody please tell me if cordova webview run html5 better speed? I will spend more time with it. If it does not, can anybody suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Just different. Cordova launches SO Webview that is linked to your SO version and never changes until you receive a SO Update.

On the other hand Google Navigator version depends on if you have installed or not the last version

For example my Nexus4 SO is in v30 and Chrome APP is in v35 and probably faster than v30.